# How to hide a form field based on the previously form field's selected option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I want to hide a form field ("metodo") if the user select some ("Conta" or "Retirada") of the six options the previously form field ("operacao") has.

I've tried hiding (.hide()) the "metodo" form field with the .change() function based on the value (.val()) of the selected option of the "operacao" form field.

```
<form method=post>
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <label for="operador">Operador</label>
    {{ render_field(form.operador) }}
    <br  />
    <label for="operacao">Operação</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="operacao" name="operacao" required="">
        <option value="Foto Documento">Foto Documento</option>
        <option value="Revelação">Revelação</option>
        <option value="Foto Produto">Foto Produto</option>
        <option value="Ótica">Ótica</option>
        <option value="Conta">Conta</option>
        <option value="Retirada">Retirada</option>
    </select>       
    <br/>
    <label for="metodo">Método de Pagamento</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="metodo" name="metodo" required="">
        <option value="Não se aplica">Não se aplica</option>
        <option value="Dinheiro">Dinheiro</option>
        <option value="Cartão">Cartão</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="valor">Valor</label>
    {{ render_field(form.valor) }}
    <br />
    <label for="observacao">Observação*</label>
    {{ render_field(form.observacao) }}
    <small id="observacaoHelp" class="form-text text-muted">*Opcional</small>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Salvar</button>
</form>

<!--I have typed the output of the render_field(form.operacao) and 
render_field(form.metodo) to make it easier to visualize. -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#operacao").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Conta" || "Retirada"){
        $("#metodo").hide();
    }});
});
</script>
```

Since the options "Conta" and "Retirada in the "operacao" form field renders the form field "metodo" purposeless (and actually can be a problematic if other options aside "Não se aplica" are selected in the "metodo" form field) I want it completely hided (the option "Não se aplica" is already default on that form field, so no problem in hiding it).
However, selecting those options isn't hiding the field as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you issue is with the jQuery condition.

```
$(function(){
  $("#operacao").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Conta" || $(this).val() == "Retirada") {
      $("#metodo").hide();
    }
  });
});
```